# How can a method directly access its class variables without using self?

Tags: python, class, variables, scope

I recently switched to Python from Java for development and is still not used to some of the implicitness of Python programming.

I have a class which I have defined some class variables, how can I access the class variables within a method in Python?

```py
class Example:
    CONSTANT_A = "A"
    
    @staticmethod
    def mymethod():
        print(CONSTANT_A)
```

The above code would give me the error message: `"CONSTANT_A" is not defined"` by Pylance.

I know that I can make this work using `self.CONSTANT_A`, but `self` is referring to the Object, while I am trying to directly access to the Class variable (specifically constants).

---

#### Question

How can I directly access Class variables in Python and not through the instance?

Comment: IIRC, in Java, class methods are called static methods, right? If that's what's confusing you, check out [`@classmethod` vs `@staticmethod` in Python](/q/136097/4518341), and maybe [Meaning of `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` for beginner [duplicate\]](/q/12179271/4518341)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Also I don't get why in Python, I cannot access a Class variable in a method even if both the variable and method are in the same class. Why must I call `self.varname` in order to access `varname` even though I am not trying to access the Object's varname, but rather the Class's varname? @wjandrea

Comment: @QuanBui this is just to tell your program which to access, class instance variable and class variable

Comment: These might help: [Can I access a class variable from an instance?](/q/25577578/4518341) and [Is accessing class variables via an instance documented?](/q/10313471/4518341)

Comment: why are you using staticmethod there? and why are you using a class? 
you should just define these things on the module level if you're not using the instance.  For beginners, try to stay away from class-attributes, until you've learned what their purpose is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, you cannot access the parent scope (class)'s fields from methods without `self.` or `cls.`.

Consider using [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```py
class Example:
    CONSTANT_A = "A"
    
    @classmethod
    def mymethod(cls):
        print(cls.CONSTANT_A)
```

or directly accessing it like `Classname.attribute`:

```py
class Example:
    CONSTANT_A = "A"
    
    @staticmethod
    def mymethod():
        print(Example.CONSTANT_A)
```

Comment: Minor correction: a class is not a scope. If it were, methods could access its fields using unbound variables, like in OP's code.

Comment: You could also add `type(self).CONSTANT_A` for an instance method

Comment: Isn't `cls` just another naming for `self`? Aren't both `cls` and `self` are referring to the Object, which implicitly reference to the Class variable since the Object's variable is not available?

Comment: @Quan No, not at all. It's explained in the documentation Jongwook linked.

Comment: In classmethods, `cls` is the "type" (it is the same object as `Example`), NOT an instance of type `Example`. You can find more details in the official python documentation.

Comment: Thank you all, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

for static method, you can access the class variable by `<class_name>.<variable>`.

```
>>> class Example:
...     CONSTANT_A = "A"
...     @staticmethod
...     def mymethod():
...         print(Example.CONSTANT_A) 
... 
>>> 
>>> x = Example.mymethod()
A # print value
```